# SurfaceView Initialized from XML

Tags: android, xml, layout, surfaceview

For some reason that I don't understand, when I create my SurfaceView from an XML layout the surface is cleared every refresh. But if I just initalize it in code without the XML the drawn surface is retained.

If I initialize the SurfaceView like this it is drawn blank every refresh:

```
app = (App) findViewById(R.id.app);
app.setActivity(this);
```

If I initialize the SurfaceView like this the surface's drawing is retained every refresh:

```
app = new App(this);
setContentView(app);
app.setActivity(this);
```

Here is the XML layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:clickable="true">
        <com.threedtopo.someapp.android.app
            android:id="@+id/app"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/black"
            android:clickable="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Any insight would be appreciated, thanks!

Edit: This is how the root view is being initialized in the first example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content">
            <!-- <TextView -->
            <EditText
            android:id="@+id/hidden_text"
            android:inputType="textLongMessage"
            android:autoText="true"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:editable="true"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            />
        </LinearLayout>
    <ViewSwitcher
        android:id="@+id/switcher"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/splash"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/splashscreen" />
        <com.threedtopo.someapp.android.app             android:id="@+id/app"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:clickable="true" />
    </ViewSwitcher> 
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/keyboard_layout"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content">
        <android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView
            android:id="@+id/keyboard"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This may or may not affect the difference but in latter case you assign App as root element plus you do not specify background color.

Comment: Thanks harism, I added how the root display is being initialized for the first example. Note that I tried removing the background color from all of the XML layouts and that did not change the behavior.

Comment: OK - so you must be correct. Setting the background color appears to be the culprit. I guess the changes to the XML file did not do anything until after I did a clean.

Comment: harism if you post your comment as an answer I will upvote it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to harism this has been solved. Apparently setting the background property in the XML file causes the SurfaceView to be cleared each draw.